# Tp-link AC1900 wifi card with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I can't seem to get this to work on Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.0-40-generic (it works in Windows when I tested it).
It lists with lsusb as 'TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek RTL8814AU]'

I have tried
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git;
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au;
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21

but received the message
"Good news! Module version v4.3.21_17997.20160531 for 8814au.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.4.0-40-generic"

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what happens if you try `sudo modprobe 8814au`

Comment: Thanks I tried sudo modprobe --verbose 8814au. The system just hangs. Has the output   insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/updates/dkms/8814au.ko